# iBatis query failing in spite of it working in an Oracle SQL editor

Tags: sql, oracle, ibatis

The following query is working perfectly fine in an SQL Editor (Oracle), but failing through iBatis.

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5 )
    SELECT   #col1#, 
                #col2#, 
                #col3#, 
                #col4#, 
                #col5#
                FROM DUAL
        where not exists (select 1 from TEST_TABLE where COL1 = #col1#)
```

Exception - ORA-00933 - SQL Command not properly ended.

Comment: Where are using such a complex query? you can use MERGE for this.

Comment: Honestly speaking I did not know of MERGE statement.  I will read about it and try applying in this case.  Thanks @Ivan

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  iBatis somehow needs parenthesis to identify sub queries.  I could resolve the issue by adding brackets around the outer `SELECT` clause.

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5 )
    ( SELECT   #col1#, 
                #col2#, 
                #col3#, 
                #col4#, 
                #col5#
                FROM DUAL
        where not exists (select 1 from TEST_TABLE where COL1 = #col1#))
```